# CSS detect if selector has div next to it and change the former

Tags: html, css

I have the following html but I need to write CSS to do the following.

IF .hint or any other div follows `<div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>` then to display `<div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>`

```
<md-input-container flex="">
  <label>New password</label>
  <input autocomplete="no" type="password">
  <div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>
  <div class="hint">Confirm your password with any change</div>
</md-input-container>
```

I have tried using `+` `~` in the css but this ends up selecting the `.hint` div

ie: `md-input-container .md-errors-spacer ~ .hint`

I just want to be able to check if .hint exists and then alter `.md-errors-spacer`

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/bettercalldough/pen/dJXOdP)

Comment: This is more of an angular question than a html css question

Comment: @SynchroDynamic not really.

Comment: When do you want it happen? On page load or ?

Comment: Not familiar with Angular but if there is guaranteed to be nothing after div.hint in the actual element tree regardless of whether div.hint itself appears, then you can get away with .md-errors-spacer:not(:last-child).